# finding suitable column matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I have a row matrix A:1*n and need to find suitable column matrix B:n*1 to multiplying existing row matrix B*A=C to reach inversible square matrix C:n*n ?

Comment: for $n>1$ that is not possible. think about the rank of $BA$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For
$$
A=[a_1,a_2, \cdots ,a_n] \quad B=[b_1,b_2, \cdots ,b_n]^T
$$
we have:
$$
BA= 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\
b_2\\
.\\
b_n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1a_1&b_1a_2\cdots b_1a_n\\
b_2a_1&b_2a_2\cdots b_2a_n\\
.\\
b_na_1&b_na_2\cdots b_na_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

so the columns of $BA$ are clearly not lineraly independent.